# Trace-free part of the second fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tensors

I found this notion on this part of a survey by S. Brendle:

[image: trace]

What exactly is the definition (without using basis) of the “trace-free part of the second fundamental form”?

For me, the second fundamental form of a hypersurface $\Sigma$ of $S^3$ with unit normal vector field $\eta$ is, at a point $p \in \Sigma$, defined by

$$ A_p(v) = - \nabla_v \eta, \quad v \in T_p \Sigma.$$

Comment: I guess Brendle is using a nonstandard definition of mean curvature, i.e., the sum of the principal curvatures rather than half that.  At any rate, given a linear map $T$ on a $2$-dimensional vector space, its trace-free part is $T-\frac12\text{tr}(T) I$. You can check this identity by taking the second fundamental form to be diagonal with entries $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$. Then both sides will be $1+\frac14(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin You are right. Simon Brendle uses that $H=\lambda_1+\lambda_2.$ See page 2 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.6938.pdf